# How do I check linearity of a splined variable?

Tags: r, survival

I made a model with a splined variable.

```
coxph(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ age+anaemia+creatinine_phosphokinase+
ns(ejection_fraction, knots=c(15))+serum_creatinine+hypertension, data=HF)
```

This is the code I used to check `ejection_fraction`'s linearity. How can I check its linearity *after* I've applied a spline?

```
X <- HF$ejection_fraction
Y <- resid(reducedMod, type = "martingale")
plot(X, Y, pch = 20, col = "darkgray",
     xlab = "Ejection Fraction", ylab = "Martingale Residual")+
abline(h = 0) +
lines(smooth.spline(X, Y, df = 7), lty = 2, lwd = 2)
```

Comment: I suppose I was trying to find out how to code it.

Comment: You test for significance of the set of spline terms.

Comment: If you've used a spline you already suspect that the relationship between outcome and predictor isn't strictly linear. To test for linearity per se, test the non-linear terms of the spline. That's probably not what you want here, however: you seem to want to see if the spline worked OK. For that you can proceed as you do for any predictor: start with the _full model with the spline_ and plot _its_ martingale residuals against the values of the continuous variable. The smoothed plot should be reasonably flat.

Comment: @EdM That's exactly what I wanted to know! I realize I never updated the model in the code above to the one *with* the spline. Thank You.